# scrambled array order when using fwrite

Tags: c, io

I am attempting to write arrays out to a binary file using fwrite, and as I am writing a stream of x-points followed by a stream of y-points the order is important. I expect the output to be written so that my file consists of a pair of arrays:

```
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If I write out to a text file using `fprintf` and looping over the array index I get the expected output order, however when I use the fwrite code below the data is written out of order. Since I am using a simple array I was expecting that the fwrite calls would simple write out the entire array in order.  Is this not the case and I am misunderstanding or is my error elsewhere?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>

#define cache_align 0x40

#define xmin -2
#define ymin -2
#define xrange 4
#define yrange 4
#define xres 5
#define yres 5
#define num_particles (xres*yres)

int main(){

  unsigned int stepnum = 0;

  double* cx = aligned_alloc(cache_align, sizeof(double)*num_particles);
  double* cy = aligned_alloc(cache_align, sizeof(double)*num_particles);

  for(int ii=0; ii<xres; ii++){
    for(int kk=0; kk<yres; kk++){
      cx[ii*yres + kk] = ii;
      cy[ii*yres + kk] = kk;
    }
  }


  FILE* outfile;
  char fname[100];
  sprintf(fname, "out.bin");
  outfile = fopen(fname,"wb");
  if(!outfile){
    printf("Unable to open output file!");
  } else {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(cx,sizeof(double),num_particles,outfile);
    written = fwrite(cy,sizeof(double),num_particles,outfile);
    fclose(outfile);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Edit: I should add I am checking the data output using python:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.fromfile('out.bin','double',-1)
```

Comment: The fromfile() format is intended to read only data produced on the same machine with tofile().  The format isn't documented. So you're in uncharted waters.  In particular, the source looks like numpy for Windows does some kind of padding: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/945c308e96fb815729e8f8aeb0ad6b39b8bdf84a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/convert.c#L148

Comment: Your code populates the arrays `cx` with values between `0` and `xres` (a positive value) and `cy` with values between `0` and `yres` (also positive), and then uses `fwrite()` to output both arrays.   How is it that you expect the output file to contain negative values????

Comment: @Peter, sorry about that, I had more complex code initially but simplified my minimal example and forgot to change my expected output.  Now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear whether you have omitted all validations and error checking for brevity, or if that is just something you have ignored. Your indexing issue is correctly addressed by the other answer. If your omission of validations and error checks was intentional, then you can largely ignore the following, if not, then consider *you* are responsible for validating each step in your code this is relied upon by subsequent operation.

At minimum, that means validating all *memory allocations*, file *opening* and file *closing* (for writes), and the *number of objects written* to the data file on writes. The validations are just simple checks to insure you have a valid block of memory, a valid file stream, that the number of object you intended to write were actually written, and that there were no stream errors on file close after write. They could be as simple as the following for file stream open:

```
FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (fname, "wb") : stdout;

if (!fp) {  /* validate file is open for writing */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

For memory allocations:

```
/* validate all memory allocation */
if (!(cx = aligned_alloc (cache_align, sizeof *cx * NPART))) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - cx.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Validating the number of objects written to file (your `written` is `nobj` and your `num_particles` is `NPART` -- I hate typing):

```
    /* validate the number of objects written to file */
    if ((nobj = fwrite (cx, sizeof *cx, NPART, fp)) != NPART)
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: fwrite failure - cx.\n");
    if ((nobj = fwrite (cy, sizeof *cy, NPART, fp)) != NPART)
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: fwrite failure - cy.\n");
```

For steam close after writing to a file:

```
    if (fclose (fp))  /* validate the stream closure for writes */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fclose failed, data is suspect.\n");
```

Finally, don't forget to free the memory you allocate. Get it the habit of tracking your allocations and freeing each allocation rather than relying on `exit` doing it for your. It will be routine when you begin allocating further down in various functions later. Also run your code though a memory error checking program, like `valgrind` on Linux, to insure its correct use.

While you are free to check you data in whatever you like, simply writing a validation function can take the uncertainty out of the process. For example, you can simply pass the existing arrays to a validation function and have that function read the data you have written and provide a comparison of each value. It only needs to indicate whether an error occurred. If not, then you are fine. For example, a simple check function (using static arrays for simplicity) could be:

```
int chkdatafile (char *fn, double *a, double *b)
{    
    int err = 0;
    size_t nobj = 0;
    double cx[NPART] = {0.0}, cy[NPART] = {0.0};
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, "rb");

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fopen failed '%s'.\n", fn);
        return 1;
    }

    /* validate NPART object read into each array */
    if ((nobj = fread (cx, sizeof *cx, NPART, fp)) != NPART) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fread failure - cx.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((nobj = fread (cy, sizeof *cx, NPART, fp)) != NPART) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fread failure - cy.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fclose (fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < NPART; i++) /* validate cx read from file */
        if (cx[i] != a[i]) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: cx[%2d] : (read) %02.0lf != %02.0lf\n",
                    i, cx[i], a[i]);
            err = 1;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < NPART; i++) /* validate cy read from file */
        if (cy[i] != b[i]) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: cx[%2d] : (read) %02.0lf != %02.0lf\n",
                    i, cy[i], b[i]);
            err = 1;
        }

    return err;
}
```

You could call it from your program with something similar to:

```
    if (chkdatafile (fname, cx, cy))
        fprintf (stderr, "error: data in '%s' is invalid.\n", fname);
```

Like I said, if you intentionally omitted the checks, then I'm not telling you anything you don't already know, if they weren't, then get in the habit early of always validating anything that is later relied upon in your code. It will save you a lot of time debugging, etc., in the long run.

Putting all the pieces together, taking the output filename as the first argument to the program (and simply writing the values to `stdout` if no output filename is given), you could provide minimum checks as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define cache_align 0x40

#define XRES 5
#define YRES 5
#define NPART (XRES*YRES)

int chkdatafile (char *fn, double *a, double *b);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t nobj;
    double *cx, *cy;
    char *fname = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdout";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (fname, "wb") : stdout;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file is open for writing */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* validate all memory allocation */
    if (!(cx = aligned_alloc (cache_align, sizeof *cx * NPART))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - cx.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(cy = aligned_alloc (cache_align, sizeof *cy * NPART))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - cx.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < XRES; i++)
        for (int k = 0; k < YRES; k++) {
            cx[k * YRES + i] = i;
            cy[k * YRES + i] = k;
        }

    if (argc > 1) {  /* validate the number of objects written */
        if ((nobj = fwrite (cx, sizeof *cx, NPART, fp)) != NPART)
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: fwrite failure - cx.\n");
        if ((nobj = fwrite (cy, sizeof *cy, NPART, fp)) != NPART)
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: fwrite failure - cy.\n");
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < NPART; i++)
            printf (" %02.0lf", cx[i]);
        putchar ('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < NPART; i++)
            printf (" %02.0lf", cy[i]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    if (fp != stdout) {
        if (fclose (fp))  /* validate the stream closure for writes */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: fclose failed, data is suspect.\n");
        if (chkdatafile (fname, cx, cy))
            fprintf (stderr, "error: data in '%s' is invalid.\n", fname);
    }

    free (cx);  /* free all allocated memory */
    free (cy);

    return 0;
}

int chkdatafile (char *fn, double *a, double *b)
{    
    int err = 0;
    size_t nobj = 0;
    double cx[NPART] = {0.0}, cy[NPART] = {0.0};
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, "rb");

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fopen failed '%s'.\n", fn);
        return 1;
    }

    /* validate NPART object read into each array */
    if ((nobj = fread (cx, sizeof *cx, NPART, fp)) != NPART) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fread failure - cx.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((nobj = fread (cy, sizeof *cx, NPART, fp)) != NPART) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fread failure - cy.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fclose (fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < NPART; i++) /* validate cx read from file */
        if (cx[i] != a[i]) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: cx[%2d] : (read) %02.0lf != %02.0lf\n",
                    i, cx[i], a[i]);
            err = 1;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < NPART; i++) /* validate cy read from file */
        if (cy[i] != b[i]) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: cx[%2d] : (read) %02.0lf != %02.0lf\n",
                    i, cy[i], b[i]);
            err = 1;
        }

    return err;
}
```

If you provide an output filename and receive no errors, all went as intended. Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thankyou for your very complete answer.  I have error checking code in my complete version, but wanted to keep the code down to a minimum for clarity.  I appreciate your comments however, and valgrind comes back clean in this case.